# Monitor Appointment Cancel Event

Tags: outlook, vsto

I am trying to run some code upon cancellation of an AppointmentItem, however two of the events that I tried to capture fire more than once (`Application.Send`, `AppointmentItem.Write`, `BeforeDelete` doesn't fire). This bring me to re-think my logic and find a suitable place to implement it. I couldn't find a reason why the two events are fired twice in my case as I am using inspector wrapper to register these events on a new inspector window and Un-registering them on inspector close event.

Please note that I want to monitor all possible scenario where an Appointment can be canceled/deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even need any inspector events? Monitor the `Application.ItemSend` event, check if you get a MeetingItem object as an argument, check that the message class is "﻿IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Resp.Neg" or Class = 55 (`OlObjectClass.olMeetingResponseNegative`).